# How to add json object from a nested json into a db-column in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, json, oracle11g, sql-insert

I need to insert json from a nested json file into a column in Oracle. For example, in the following json

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
}
}
```

I need to store the whole json:

```
"cars": {
"car1":"Ford",
"car2":"BMW",
"car3":"Fiat"
}
```

in a db column. How can i do that? I am using Oracle DB.

---

I have tried the following query but its not working. (Says clob isn't a valid datatype)

```
select x.*
    from json_tab t,
             json_table (t.json_data, '$.[*]' 
         COLUMNS
            name  VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.name',
            cars clob PATH '$.cars[*]') x;
```

I have tried the same using varchar2 datatype but it selects null.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use oracle 12c, try to experiment with this query to achieve the result you need.

```
select x.*, json_object(key 'cars' value x.cars format json) cars_json 
    from json_tab t, 
        json_table(t.json_data, '$'
                 COLUMNS
                   name  VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$.name',
                   cars VARCHAR(4000) format json PATH '$.cars[*]') as x;
```